# Set input shape of model in keras

Tags: python, input, keras, shapes

I had saw other similar question on tensor flow but didn't match my problem.

### Model:

```
# picture size
img_row = 128
img_col = 647
shape = (img_row, img_col)

img = Input(input_shape)
...
```

with result
[image: model]

### Data:

There has 1000 datas and each with shape (128, 647), and its a column of Dataframe df.
Therefore, size result and data preview are as follow:
[image]
[image]

### Problem

The problem is: when I pass the Data to Model, some size error occured.

```
train_history = model.fit(  x = df["data"],
                            y = df["genre_idx"],
                            validation_split = 0.1,
                            epochs = 30,
                            batch_size = 200,
                            verbose = 2
                         )
```

And error message are as follow:

```
Error when checking input: expected input_79 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1000, 1)
```

It might be a low question, but I didn't figure out what is the main problem of this situation and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it as a single *ndarray* which you can extract using the [.values property](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) of the data frame. The expected shape for the input is `(1000, 128, 647)`.